# In Angular2 With Bootstrap - Tooltip, Tooltip Need setup by executing javascript, How to do it?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular

Angular2 (2.0.0-rc.4)
I use Bootstrap's Tooltip, Tooltip need execute follow javascript when ready:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

In Angular2,how to execute it?

Answer (score 2):

That worked for me:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, HostListener, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTooltip]'
})
export class TooltipDirective implements OnDestroy {


  @Input()
  public appTooltip: string;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('mouseenter')
  public onMouseEnter(): void {
    const nativeElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    $(nativeElement).tooltip('show');
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave')
  public onMouseLeave(): void {
    const nativeElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    $(nativeElement).tooltip('dispose');
  }


ngOnDestroy(): void {
    const nativeElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    $(nativeElement).tooltip('dispose');
  }

}
```

registering:

1. Importing it in in app.module.ts
2. Adding it in declarations on @NgModule (file app.module.ts)

And using it like this:

```
<button title="tooltip tilte" [appTooltip]></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div data-toggle="tooltip" #tooltip></div>
```

```
class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild('tooltip') tooltip:ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.tooltip.nativeElement.tooltip();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!if i have a tooltip list,how to do it?

Comment: I don't know Bootstrap. What is "tooltip list"? What's the problem?

Comment: Hello~ It's like li(s) in ul, multi elements in a page,use ViewChildren?

Comment: I suggest you look at https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/core instead of re inventing the wheel

Comment: -_-|! tooltip is not a function